Terminator: How to close a specific layout?
About Terminator
If it is running and considering the following:
Right Click
 Layouts...
  default
  Alpha
  Beta

Where Alpha and Beta are customs layouts as follows:

Alpha  5 has windows
Beta  10 has windows

Does not matter the content/structure of each window
Suppose you open both layouts. Therefore 15 windows in total are opened.
Question

How to close a specific layout?

It by either keyboard shortcut or mouse
For example consider the requirement to close the Beta layout with its 10 windows. Therefore only Alpha layout with its 5 windows should be active
